# Cannot load an empty url

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I dont get why I got this error tho the api is working fine in postman. I have successfully logged on and what I am trying to do is to call another api using the username from login. Below is the action on how I want to call the next api, I passed the jwtToken and the username obtained from login.Can anyone point the error in my code and how to solve

```
export const getSemcode = (username) => async dispatch => {
const jwtToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwtToken').then((data) => {
    console.log('this is semcode',data);
});   

let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://xx/api/xx/GetListOfKodSesiSem',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        AntiTemperSignature: this.jwtToken,
        UserID: username,
      },
      data: username,
    json: true
  };

let param = {
    nomatrik : username
}

  return axios(param, config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.data.length > 0) {
        const { code } = response.data;
        dispatch({ type: SEMCODE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: { semCode: code } 
  });
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

}
```

Comment: I *think* your param and config are backwards in the axios call (though I'm not that familiar with axios).

Comment: hmmm I did change it to (config, param) yet it still gives the same error